# cannot convert from 'List<string>' to 'string' exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm receiving an exception like **cannot convert from 'List' to 'string'** when i'm declaring a list.

```
 var query = new List<string>(){
                    new List<string>{"a", "b","c"},
                    new List<string> {"a"}};
```

I couldn't find out the error in above.Can somebody help me in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var query = new List<List<string>>(){
                    new List<string>{"a", "b","c"},
                    new List<string> {"a"}};
```

Comment: This is correct. Basically we are declaring a List which holds list. And that List holds string datatype.

Comment: @KaipaMSarma: To be explicit, we're not declaring a list of list, we're declaring a list of list of string. If you try to add a list of int to your outer list, you'd get an error at design time.

Comment: I mean the same, Sorry if my explanation is bad ;(

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a list as string, you should do as bellow if you want a list of list of string:

```
 var query = new List<List<string>>(){
                new List<string>{"a", "b","c"},
                new List<string> {"a"}};
```

or do as bellow if you want a list of string:

```
 var query = new List<string>(){"a", "b","c"};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a List of List of strings, you can do what vc74 or Saeed suggest. If you want to end up with a single List containing all the strings from the two other, you can do :

```
var firstList = new List<string>{"a", "b","c"};
var secondList = new List<string>{"a", "b","c"};

var query = new List<string>();
query.AddRange(firstList);
query.AddRange(secondList);
```